# Is there a convention for how to shape deeply nested ElasticSearch queries?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, nested, conventions, opensearch

Very specifically, I am trying to generate an arbitrarily deeply nested ElasticSearch/OpenSearch query, and I was curious if there was 1) a convention for and 2) any performance ramifications for how to compose nesting, specifically an example like this. (These are generated examples, let's assume the values are otherwise correct and the only thing I am evaluating is the structure of the nesting itself.)

Option 1: Building the nesting out using `bool.must` clauses the whole way down:

```
  "nested": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "nested": {
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "must": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "name": "john"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        "path": "books.authors"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "path": "books"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Option 2: Omitting the `bool.must` clauses except for "where it matters":

```
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "tags",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "tags.versions",
          "query": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "tags.versions.files",
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    { 
                      "match": { 
                        "tags.versions.files.name": "file1" 
                      } 
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It makes no difference, must is only useful if you have different sibling constraints that you need to enforce.

Comment: That's perfect. The question spawned as a result of me hand-rolling the queries the second way, but noticing when I recursively built the query from a tree, it was simpler to just jam them into `bool.must` all the way down.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped, just adding as an answer if that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference, must is only useful if you have different sibling constraints that you need to enforce